# How can I adjust Doodle poll time zone?

Tags: time-zone, doodle.com

Doodle assumes that my timezone is Zurich time.

Is there any way to change it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Go to your [profile](https://beta.doodle.com/account#profile).
2. Adjust your default timezone, then it will work.

Comment: Since I guess your answer was helpful for you - why won't you accept it? :)